# Metodo apply optimizacion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Estoy usando un número de teléfono celular como ID de cliente y quiero comparar de 2 fuentes de datos (dos tablas) si el número de teléfono celular es el mismo y luego poner algunos datos (género, dirección, edad) de la tabla 2 en la tabla 1.

```
def Macheo(Tel, Genero, DNI, Edad, CP ):
    print(Tel)
    for i in range(len(Comerciales)):
        if Tel ==Comerciales.iloc[i,5]:
            Comerciales.iloc[i,27]=Genero
            Comerciales.iloc[i,14]=Edad
            Comerciales.iloc[i,13]=CP
    return 0        
Email=TablaVN.apply(lambda x: Macheo(x['Teléfono'],x['Géner'],x['DNI/CIF'],x['F.nacimi'],x['C.P.']),axis=1)
```

No quiero usar el bucle for, pero realmente no sé si puedo usar el método apply en dos DF diferentes, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Luego de comparar ambos datos que quieres hacer?

Comment: Luego de comparar ambos datos quiero Incoporar en la tabla Comerciales para ese cliente los datos genero, edad y Codigo Postal, que tiene la tabla VN.

Comment: Podrias colocarlas por favor?